# why onBackPressed() syntax is closing the app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, onbackpressed

the onBackPressed() in the signup page is okay and i put the same code in another activity and when i pressed it, the app will go back to previous activity but it will close first..

this is the code in my second activity which the app will close after i press the back arrow

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityAllusersignupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    //action bar
    actionBar = supportActionBar!!
    actionBar.title = "User Registration"
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    onBackPressed()//go back to previous activity, when back button of actionbar clicked
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

}

Comment: You're not supposed to call methods starting with the word `on` yourself. Like if you wanted to finish your activity, you should call `finish()` instead of `onBackPressed()`. You shouldn't need to be doing this anyway. Doesn't the default behavior close the activity and go back to the last one unless you have some stack of fragments inside the current activity?

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to go back to previous activity when i press the back actionbar at the top?

Comment: That should be the default behavior. You might be setting up your action bar incorrectly. It can be the built-in bar that Android provides, or it can be an element in your XML layout that you manually set to behave as the action bar.